# To talk about positivity of Lebesgue measure of projections onto axes of a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x=y\}$ such that one dimensional Lebesgue measure of $A$ is positive.

Is it true that projection of $A$ onto $x$-axis and $y$-axis is also a set of positive one dimensional Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $D$ the diagonal $\{(x,y) \in \mathbf R^2 \mid x=y\}$ and denote by $\pi(x,y) = x$ be the projection from $D$ to $\mathbf R$.  You need to be a bit careful defining the one-dimensional Lebesgue (outer) measure of a subset of $\mathbf R^2$, but for any set $A \subset D$ a reasonable definition is
$$\lambda_D^*(A) = \inf \sum_k \ell (J_k)$$
where the infimum is taken over all countable families $\{J_k\}$ of open intervals in $D$ whose union covers $A$.

Let $\{I_k\}$ be a covering of $\pi(A)$ by open intervals. Then $\{\pi^{-1}(I_k)\}$ is a covering of $A$ in $D$, and moreover each set $\pi^{-1}(I_k)$ is an interval in $D$ with $\ell(\pi^{-1}(I_k)) = \sqrt{2} \ell(I_k)$. Thus
$$\lambda_D^*(A) \le \sum_k \ell(\pi^{-1}(I_k)) = \sqrt{2}  \sum_k \ell(I_k),$$and by taking the infimum over all covers $\{I_k\}$ of $\pi(A)$ it follows that
$$\lambda_D^*(A) \le \sqrt{2} \lambda^*(\pi(A)).$$

A simple consequence is that $\lambda_D^*(A) > 0$ implies $\lambda^*(\pi(A))) > 0$.

Comment: Yes! That was easy... Thank you...